# ¿Cómo soluciono bucle infinito?

Tags: c#, vscode

Estoy realizando un bucle con el Visual Studio Code y genera un bucle infinito lo cuál me impide continuar con el programa. ¿Cómo lo soluciono?

```
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numero1;
            int numero2;
            Console.WriteLine("Introduce dos numeros");
            Console.ReadLine();

            bool esPrimo = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Introduce numero1");
            numero1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Introduce numero2");
            numero2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            while (esPrimo)
            {
               if(numero1 % numero1 == 0)
               {
                    esPrimo = false;
                    break;
               }
               numero1++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"El número {(esPrimo?"es" : "no es")} primo.");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tienes `numero1 % numero1` que siempre te dara cero. ¿No será `numero2`?

Comment: ¿Que deseas realizar, si los dos números son o no Primos?

Comment: @Jorgesys exactamente es lo que quiero saber

Comment: @CandidMoe en principio me debería dar siempre 1, aunque puede ser que lo haya planteado mal

Comment: @JuanAarónUrgel La condición  `if(numero1 % numero1 == 0)` siempre daría como resultado `verdadero`, pues dividir un número entre si mismo siempre obtendría como resultado 1 y el resto obtenido por el operador `%` seria siempre seria igual a cero, por tanto en la primera iteración la sentencia `break;`haria detener el bucle, no se por que afirmas que se produce un bucle infinito, lo cierto es que siempre  retornaría un solo resultado, retornaría siempre que el número no es primo, lo que puede ser erróneo en muchas ocasiones, pero nunca surgiría un bucle infinito.

Answer (score 1):

Incluyo una solución para determinar si un número es o no un número  primo.

Primero dejemos claro que los números primos son aquellos que solo se dividen entre sí mismos y el número 1, por tanto un algoritmo a fuerza bruta, puede ser dividir el numero entre todos los números mayores que uno y menores que si mismo, si se encontrara un solo divisor en ese rango, podemos concluir que es un número compuesto, es decir no es primo.

Para encontrar los divisores de un número por el método a fuerza bruta mencionado, yo utilizo un algoritmo mejorado, limitando el numero de iteraciones necesarias, lo explico con un ejemplo: Si quisiera encontrar los divisores del numero 45, tenemos dos divisores el 1 y el 45 que se obtienen directamente, para determinar los demás, no es necesario dividir desde 2 hasta 44; los resultados serian los siguientes:

45 / 2 = 22 con resto =1. es decir 2 no es divisor de 45, ni lo será 22.

45 / 3 = 15 con resto =0. es decir 3 y 15, ambos son divisores 45.

45 / 4 = 11 con resto =1. es decir 4 no es divisor de 45, ni lo será 11.

45 / 5 = 9 con resto =0. es decir 5 y 9, ambos son divisores 45.

45 / 6 = 7 con resto =3. es decir 6 no es divisor de 45, ni lo será 7.

Es decir,cada ves que encontremos un divisor exacto, habremos encontrado en realidad dos, pues cuando el resto es cero, tanto el divisor y el cociente, son divisores exactos del dividendo y además seria solo necesario realizar la división desde 2 hasta un valor menor o igual a la raíz cuadrada del número investigado.
La raíz cuadrada de 45 es 6.7082, por tanto con las iteraciones desde 2 hasta 6, son suficientes para encontrar todos sus divisores.

A continuación el código que resuelve el problema planteado, usando estos conceptos.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int numero1;
        bool esPrimo = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Introdusca un numero mayor que cero");
        numero1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (numero1 < 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("El número introducido no es valido, no se acepta un numero menor que 1");
            Console.ReadLine();
            return;
        }

        double divisor = 2;
        while (divisor <= Math.Sqrt(numero1))
        {
            if (numero1 % divisor == 0)
           {
                esPrimo = false;
                break;
           }
           divisor++;
        }
        if (esPrimo)
            Console.WriteLine(numero1.ToString()+" es un número primo.");
        else
            Console.WriteLine(numero1.ToString() + " no es un número primo.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

---

Edición.
Edito la respuesta, por que me han señalado, que no he dado respuesta a la pregunta, ya que en ella se plantea que se produce un ciclo infinito.
Para este tema coloqué un comentario a la pregunta donde explico lo siguiente:

La condición `if(numero1 % numero1 == 0)` siempre daría como resultado verdadero, pues dividir un número entre si mismo siempre obtendría como resultado 1 y el resto obtenido por el operador `%` seria siempre igual a cero, por tanto en la primera iteración la sentencia break, haría detener el bucle; no se por que en la pregunta se afirma que se produce un bucle infinito, lo cierto es que siempre se saldría del bucle en la primera iteración y siempre se  retornaría un solo resultado, retornaría siempre que el número no es primo, lo que puede ser erróneo en muchas ocasiones, pero nunca surgiría un bucle infinito.

Comment: Eduardo, si me permites una sugerencia, incluye en la respuesta el comentario dónde explicas la razón por la que se produce el ciclo infinito. Luego la explicación relacionada con los números primos es un plus. A simple vista parece que tú respuesta no tiene relación con la pregunta. Es cierto que el programa se trata de  encontrar los números primos pero no es lo que está planteado en la pregunta.

Comment: @PabloGutiérrez No hay ciclo infinito, en la pregunta se plantea eso, no es posible; coloqué un comentario  a la pregunta donde lo expongo, La condición`if(numero1 % numero1 == 0)` siempre resultaría verdadero, por tanto en la primera iteración se sale del bucle; el autor de la pregunta a lo mejor en otra versión de su código tuvo un bucle infinito, tal ves hizo cambios sin resultados y planteo una pregunta que no se ajusta a lo que sucede con el código actual; pero en el código de su pregunta no hay bucle infinito, solo hay un intento de bucle que siempre terminará en la primera iteración .

Comment: @PabloGutiérrez A no ser que el valor introducido por el usuario sea cero, que entonces terminará en un error en tiempo de ejecución de división por cero.

Comment: Aunque es una respuesta interesante.. no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta... entiendo la definicion de numero primo, pero esta en el sitio por lo menos 2 veces mas... Y luego, nadie vendra a esta pregunta para ver que es un numero primo... fijate que en ningun momento en el titulo o la pregunta se habla de numero primo.. solo en el codigo... Esto es como critica constructiva, de que esta respuesta hubiera estado mejor en una pregunta sobre que es un numero primo... y no en esta, que es solo un error de programacion...

Comment: @gbianchi Ya, ahora si entiendo lo que quieres decirme y lo que tal ves también trató de decirme Pablo Gutiérrez. Pero yo solo traté de ir la fondo del problema, ya me doy cuenta, que eso no contribuye a que en el sitio, los demás usuarios encuentren esta respuesta cuando busquen por el tema donde es fuerte "los números primos". Pero aunque ya llevo varios meses en el sitio, tengo todavía la duda de que hacer ante este tipo de preguntas, donde en el enunciado se plantea un error o un efecto cualquiera, que no puede ocurrir según el código que se coloca.

Comment: siempre que dudes, el [chat] abre las 24 horas